# Passing 2 values from Itemtemplates to code-behind

Tags: asp.net, gridview

whats wrong with this code and i am getting this error:

`Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'RenderName(string, string)' has some invalid arguments`

```
<ItemTemplate>

<asp:Label ID="lblName" Text='<%# RenderName(Eval("Name"), Eval("Value")) %>'  runat="server" />

</ItemTemplate>

public string RenderName(string name, string value)
{
  //do stuffs..
}
```

Comment: Can you remove public from method and then try ?

Comment: This should work, see this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479353.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the return type of Eval() is an object (and I suspect it is), that would explain the error you're seeing.  Maybe change your function to:

```
RenderName(object nameString, object valueString)
```

Then within the function, check the passed params for null, and either re-cast them to strings, or simply call ToString() on them.

Note: I'm not at a place where I can verify this in my own development environment, so apologies if this approach has a few hiccups.

Answer (score 0):

the reason i was getting error is because i was not converting type

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblName" Text='<%# RenderName(Eval("Name").ToString(), Eval("Value").ToString()) %>'  runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

its working as expected.